# No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\dell\\Documents\\New folder\\IBM\\image0.png'

Tags: python

I am trying to build handwritten model here. I am just a student so can someone help me with this problem. should arrange my folder in a specific order or something else.

[image: my image]

Comment: Hi, please don't upload image when it comes to code. You can paste code here with formatting (past code, select text and click `{}` block)

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1):

The issue you see is cause a standard windows path expects just one `\` to navigate the file tree. You may correctly escape it by using double back-slashes `"Users\\dell\\Documents\\..."` in your string, it should be interpreted by your python code as `"Users\dell\Documents\..."`

Use the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for it. It's os agnostic and it's a good practice if you want to share your code.

```py
import os
filepath = os.path.join("c:", "Users", "dell", "Documents", "New folder", "IBM", "image0.png")
```

If the error persists. Check that the path of the image is effectively the correct one.